# How to pass the UDP port number as parameter using Pyshark to read protocol?

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, tshark, pyshark

I am able to decode GPRS-NS protocol using UDP port number "0-65535" in wireshark but i cannot see data in PyShark. How to pass UDP port number as parameter in File capture method?

Comment: Do you have some trial code? What did you try so far? I have found the parameter `bpf_filter='udp port 0-65535'` but it was shown for `LiveCapture`. Did you try that parameter anyway?

Comment: @Alex_p          cap = pyshark.FileCapture("pcapfilepath")...i am reading file with File Capture